# Retrieving input value using name property only (VueJS Nested forms)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a parent form with three other child forms inside. I have added a AntiForgeryToken to one of the child forms to practice implementing that security measure but the input tag only includes a name property. I will have to do this for each of the forms. The forms all have refs so typically when I retrieve the values from the form I rely on v-model which I set. I cannot set a v-model input tag of the antiForgeryToken as asp.net mvc Html.AntiForgeryToken() creates the tag automatically with only a value and name property.

Therefore, how do I access parent form and child form's input value of the antiforgerytoken with a name only?

I tried this.$refs['form1'].getElementsByName('__RequestVerificationToken')[0].value but it says its not a valid function.

I found an example on here using form.querySelector() but I have multiple forms and some nested so using a index number for form[0].querySelector() could get confusing. Hoping for a better solution.